# Can Nakama-cpp be used with Godot?

Tags: c++, godot-4

Can "Nakama C/C++ Client SDK" be used with "Godot 4 using C++ GDExtension API" ?

- [Nakama C++ on Github](https://github.com/heroiclabs/nakama-cpp)
- [Godot C++ on Github](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-cpp)

If yes, what are the procedures for using these together ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Nakama Godot SDK? https://github.com/heroiclabs/nakama-godot/releases/tag/v3.3.1